# Error when rectangular region of interest goes out of bounds - opencv

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, dlib, imshow

My script detects a face and then tracks it using dlib correlation tracker algorithm.

I'm trying to show each tracked face in a separate window using `cv2.imshow(track_index, face_img)` where `face_image` is the region of interest of the face cropped from the frame captured from a video, using `dlib.rectangle` coordinates.

Part of the code is shown below:

```
                    #get the updated tracker position
                    pos = tracker.get_position()
                    pos = dlib.rectangle(
                        int(pos.left()),
                        int(pos.top()),
                        int(pos.right()),
                        int(pos.bottom()),
                    )
                    #draw a bounding box around the tracked face
                    cv2.rectangle(image, (pos.left(), pos.top()), (pos.right(), pos.bottom()),
                                  (100, 200, 100))
                    #crop the face from the frame
                    face_img = image[pos.top():pos.bottom(),pos.left():pos.right()]
                    #refers to the number of the track created
                    track_index = "track no.{}".format(trc - i)
                    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX
                    cv2.putText(image, track_index, (pos.left(), pos.bottom() +12), font, 0.5, (255, 255, 0))
                    #show the tracked face
                    cv2.imshow(track_index, face_img)
```

This works fine until a face goes out of bounds or appears for the first time being half outside one of the borders of the frame. In this cases the program stops and throws a size error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Developing space/facetrack/hog_detect_face_track.py", line 44, in <module>
    cv2.imshow(track_index, face_img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

How can i force the ROI inside the frame borders to stop this error from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Put boundary check on the ROI.

```
h,w = image.shape[:2]
face_img = image[max(0,pos.top()):min(pos.bottom(),h),max(0,pos.left()):min(pos.right(),w)]
```